# Wilcox test and p values on grouped boxplot

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to calculate the statistics and plot the significant p values for each Cell_type (20_p1, 4_p1, etc) across ROI(between Reg1 and Reg2, Reg1 and Reg3, Reg2 and Reg3).
This is my data frame:

```
structure(list(Value = c(4.621072089, 12.59398496, 0, 0, 10.16507385, 
23.37278107, 8.474576271, 0, 7.397959184, 11.02803738, 1.694915254, 
4.347826087, 9.6024006, 27.98053528, 8.450704225, 0, 8.78112713, 
19.33471933, 0, 0, 20.44534413, 27.79809802, 20.51282051, 50, 
28.00150546, 45.01811594, 26.47058824, 50, 0, 0.113765643, 0.266666667, 
0, 0.520833333, 0.393700787, 0.595238095, 0, 0.875912409, 0.965517241, 
1.731601732, 0), Cell_type = c("20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", 
"20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", "20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", 
"20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", "20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", 
"20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", "20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", 
"20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", "20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1", 
"20_p1", "4_p1", "8_p1", "68_p1"), Area = c("GC1", "GC1", "GC1", 
"GC1", "GC2", "GC2", "GC2", "GC2", "GC3", "GC3", "GC3", "GC3", 
"GC4", "GC4", "GC4", "GC4", "GC5", "GC5", "GC5", "GC5", "GC_sc1", 
"GC_sc1", "GC_sc1", "GC_sc1", "GC_sc2", "GC_sc2", "GC_sc2", "GC_sc2", 
"Foll1", "Foll1", "Foll1", "Foll1", "Foll2", "Foll2", "Foll2", 
"Foll2", "Foll3", "Foll3", "Foll3", "Foll3"), ROI = c("Reg1", 
"Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", 
"Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", 
"Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg1", "Reg2", "Reg2", "Reg2", "Reg2", "Reg2", 
"Reg2", "Reg2", "Reg2", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", 
"Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3", "Reg3"), Site = c("Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
"Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

The code that I used are the following:

```
p= ggplot(Data, aes(x=ROI, y=Value, fill=ROI)) +
geom_boxplot() +geom_point()+
theme_classic()+ylim(0,100) +
facet_grid(cols=vars(Cell_type), rows=vars(Site)) +
rotate_x_text(angle = 45) 
df_wilcox <- Data %>%
group_by(Cell_type, ROI) %>%
pairwise_wilcox_test(Value ~ ROI) %>%
add_y_position(step.increase = 0.02)
```

It gives error: ""Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
Caused by error in `pull()`:
! Can't extract columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `ROI` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. One is that you have grouped your data frame by `ROI` as well as `Cell_type`, but `pairwise_wilcox_test` needs to compare different `ROI` levels within each grouping, so you must only group by `Cell_type`.

The second issue I ran into is specific to your sample data, in that two of the groups within `68_p1` have zero variance and this seems to cause an error in the calculation. I have therefore had to filter this cell type out:

```r
df_wilcox <- Data %>%
  filter(Cell_type != '68_p1') %>%
  group_by(Cell_type) %>%
  pairwise_wilcox_test(., Value ~ ROI) %>%
  add_xy_position()

p + stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox, label = "p.adj.signif", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

It may be easiest to do the whole thing in the `ggpubr` framework:

```r
ggboxplot(Data, 'ROI', 'Value', facet.by = 'Cell_type',
          fill = 'ROI') +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(0.3)) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c('Reg1', 'Reg2'),
                                        c('Reg1', 'Reg3'),
                                        c('Reg2', 'Reg3'))) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 90) +
  ylim(c(0, 100)) +
  facet_grid(Site~Cell_type) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: the following codes return some significance 'pv <- Data %>%
  filter(Cell_type !='68_p1') %>%
  group_by(Cell_type) %>%
  summarize(Kruskal_pvalue = kruskal.test(Value ~ ROI)$p.value)'.  But then I don't know what comparisons are significant and how to plot the significant values (*).

Comment: You could try `p + stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox, label = "p", inherit.aes = FALSE)` or `p + stat_pvalue_manual(df_wilcox, label = "p.adj", inherit.aes = FALSE)` to get the actual p values, or p values adjusted for multiple hypothesis testing.

Comment: What I find weird (sorry for the confusion) is that with pairwise-wilcox_test I do not have any significant difference (the values that you plotted). If I run a Kruskal Wallis test, I do have significant p values, but I need to show what regions (reg) have significantly different values of cell types.

Comment: And is the data you posted your full data set?

Comment: Yes, it is a small data set of a pilot study.

Comment: Many thanks! I tried to hide the non significant values using hide.ns = TRUE in the stat_compare_means function, but it doesn't work!